# Data-Driven subscription not working properly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017, ssrs-subscription

I am using Data driven subscription to send report in Email body and as an excel attachment.

[image]

In email,I am seeing the report as Body,but report as excel attachment is missing.

The requirement is I need report to be send as an attachment and in Body in one email.How can I achieve this using Data driven subscription.

I have created table with two rows and format like 'excel' and 'mhtml' and referring the column `'REPORTFORMAT'` to Render format.

Please let me know how can i send both in one email

Comment: can you show what your "REPORTFORMAT" column value is? I have my doubts on rendering both excel and MHTML in a single subscription.

Comment: @Harry-  I am having two rows for subscription dataset with "REPORTFORMAT" column value as "excel" in one row and second row as "mhtml".

Comment: each row of data will turn into a separate run of the subscription.. that is how Data Driven subscription works. See answer below from Hannover

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it automatically - **Include Report** determines whether the report is included as either an embedded report or attachment but cannot do both.

> Include Report: Select this option to embed **or** attach a copy of the report. The format of the report is determined by the rendering format you select.

[MS Docs: Create Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/create-and-manage-subscriptions-for-native-mode-report-servers?view=sql-server-ver15)

You current process with two rows should be creating two reports - one with an attachment and one with it embedded.

You could add the data in the report body in the Comment field but the data would need to be converted in to an HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the string "EXCELOPENXML" as the rendering format, then it will work. It used to work with the string "Excel" only but now it no longer works like that. With Word you also need to use the string "WORDOPENXML". You will then get the reports as attachment files, as per your requirement.

Charles